# Are there a way to block queries that come to another server?

Tags: asp.net, angular, security, asp.net-core

I made a Json web token to protect my services but now somebody has made a lot of queries on my data base using my login service. Are there a way to block queries that come to another server?

The queries or attacks to my server come from different ips and different countries.

I use angular 9 and asp.net core.

```
// POST: api/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UsuarioLogin usuarioLogin)
    {
        var _userInfo = await AutenticarUsuarioAsync(usuarioLogin.Usuario, usuarioLogin.Password);
        if (_userInfo != null)
        {
            return Ok(new { token = GenerarTokenJWT(_userInfo) });
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should block cross-origin requests (CORS). I suspect you use "enable CORS" option, you should disable it, or move to cookie based authentication or anything else.

Comment: Do you mean server blocks some IP like blacklist or reject duplicate request attack? Please describe more detail about the attack so that we can provide better solution for u.

Comment: @Lightman I have improved the description, thanks. The queries or attacks to my server come from different ips and different countries.

Comment: @ForestG thaks, I'm looking for enable CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

There are three ways to enable CORS:

- In middleware using a [named policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#np) or default policy.
- Using [endpoint routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ecors).
- With the [EnableCors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attr) attribute.

**CORS with named policy and middleware**

```
public class Startup
{
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                      "http://xxxx.com");
                              });
        });

        // services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        // app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```